# Can minecraft support an asymmetrical mesh?

Tags: models, minecraft-modding

I want to play as a Zaku II from gundam in Minecraft. I was saddened that player skins must be symmetrical. I know there's a mod that lets you play as a MLP pony, and another one that let you shapeshift into mobs.

So I decided I could just modify the player model mesh and with a shoulder spike and shield. Apply a Zaku skin to it, port the colors over onto more texture for the shoulder portions, and add it to the shiftable list. Then modify a gun mod to turn a gun into a ZMP-78.

Before I get started on this though, I need to know if Minecraft will support an asymmetrical mesh.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just try it? It would take like... 5 minutes?

Anyways, if I'm not mistaken, Minecraft doesn't work with meshes. It's just a bunch of rectangular parallelepipeds stuck into each other (or at least it WAS like that some time ago.)

Comment: I guess he wasn't asking if it supports it on-the-fly, but if it could be _made_ it support them via some configuration or stuff. If that was so, the question would make sense.